# How to create working Breadcrumbs for Hugo?

Tags: breadcrumbs, hugo

It's unbelievable how difficult is to find solid information about slightly more advanced techniques with Hugo.

After quite a while searching I’ve found [this article](https://gohugohq.com/partials/breadcrumb-partial-with-structured-data-in-hugo/) with a very nice way to implement breadcrumbs for Hugo.

I modified it a little bit to not add an unnecessary link to the last trail and to make use of i18n to translate the URL segments into something more human-readable. I also made a small workaround to remove some unwanted trails that doesn't match a translated entry:

```
{{- $url := replace .Permalink ( printf "%s" ( "/" | absLangURL ) ) "" -}}
{{- $url := replace .Permalink ( printf "%s" ( "/" | absLangURL ) ) "" -}}
{{- $.Scratch.Add "path" ( "/" | absLangURL ) -}}

{{- $.Scratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" ( "/" | absLangURL ) "name" "home" "position" 1 )) -}}
{{- range $index, $element := split $url "/" -}}
  {{- $.Scratch.Add "path" $element -}}
  {{- $.Scratch.Add "path" "/" -}}
  {{- if ne $element "" -}}
    {{- $.Scratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" ($.Scratch.Get "path") "name" . "position" (add $index 2))) -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{{ range $.Scratch.Get "breadcrumb" }}{{ if ne .position 1 }},{{ end }}{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": {{ .position }},
        "item": {
          "@id": "{{ .url }}",
          "name": "{{ .name }}"
        }
    }{{ end }}]
}
</script>

<nav class="breadcrumb">
  {{- $length := len ($.Scratch.Get "breadcrumb") -}}

  {{- range $index, $.Scratch.Get "breadcrumb" -}}

    <!--
    Assigning a constant as default value for i18n function
    if it doesn't match any entry
    Then check if current Breadcrumb item matches this constant,
    which means that part shouldn't be one of Breadcrumb's trail
    -->
    {{- $i18n := i18n ( print "breadcrumbs-" .name ) | default "__INTERNAL__" -}}

    {{- if not ( eq ($i18n) "__INTERNAL__" ) -}}

      {{ if eq ( (int .position) ) $length }}
  <span class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ $i18n }}</span>
      {{- else -}}
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="{{ .url }}" >{{ $i18n }}</a>
      {{- end -}}

    {{- end -}}

  {{ end }}
</nav>
```

It works very nicely except that as far as I could notice so far while navigating through Pagination links everything starts duplicating N times as far as the Pagination Page increases (i.e twice of Page 2, thrice for Page 3 and so on).

I've searched even more and found [a similar implementation](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/implementing-breadcrumb-navigation-in-hugo/1048/9?u=magnusthorek) in which there's no duplication... but the links are all messed up, the URL of each trail is a concatenation of all links of all trails o.O

I try to avoid asking things on Hugo's "forum" because the answers given there are most of the times hard to understand, incomplete or with "pseudo-pseudo-codes".

Does anyone know how to make this work and could lend me a hand?

Comment: It's sad, but understand you. That guy.... beep, guess that's his name, his answers are so f**king hard to understand that most of the times people just sit and wait for him to code what he was talking about. Hugo docs has a LOT of content but hardly 50% of it applies to real case scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been forced to stop coding but since this question popped up a notification for me today, let me show what I did to solve the problem proposed in the question back there, even though I can't really explain why this happens -OR- if this still happens nowadays in newer versions of Hugo (I stopped using v0.28)

Well, after MUCH testing, I simply initialized a Template Variable with the scope of the “dot” that’s passed to the Partial Template when it's called and, in the Partial, instead of calling the Scratch from the context of the dollar-sign (or whatever it’s called in Hugo/Go) I used this variable I initialized:

**list.html**

```
{{ partial "breadcrumbs.html" . }}
```

**partials/breadcrumbs.html**

```
{{ $dot := . }}
{{ $dot.Scratch.Set "path" "" }}
{{ $dot.Scratch.Set "breadcrumb" slice }}

<!-- Rest of the code in the original question -->
```

And from them on, instead of, for example:

```
{{ $.Scratch.Add "path" $element }}
```

I used:

```
{{ $dot.Scratch.Add "path" $element }}
```

And all Pagination elements worked without duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/sections/#example-breadcrumb-navigation) and building on [Lars's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105769/31629):

1. Create a file named `breadcrumbs.html` in the folder `layouts/partials` of your Hugo project or theme

```html
<ol  class="nav navbar-nav">
    {{ template "breadcrumbnav" (dict "p1" . "p2" .) }}
</ol>
{{ define "breadcrumbnav" }}
{{ if .p1.Parent }}
{{ template "breadcrumbnav" (dict "p1" .p1.Parent "p2" .p2 )  }}
{{ else if not .p1.IsHome }}
{{ template "breadcrumbnav" (dict "p1" .p1.Site.Home "p2" .p2 )  }}
{{ end }}
<li{{ if eq .p1 .p2 }} class="active"{{ end }}>
    <a href="{{ .p1.Permalink }}">{{ .p1.Title }}</a>
</li>
{{ end }}
```

2. Include `breadcrumbs.html` where you need it with:

```html
{{ partial "breadcrumbs.html" . }}
```

This produces links (including the sections) that are all valid.

Comment: Great recursive implementation, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would improve it with `<li{{ if eq .p1 .p2 }} class="breadcrumb-item active"{{ else }} class="breadcrumb-item"{{ end }}>`

Answer (score 1):

It only takes 2 steps, inspired by: http://hugocodex.org/add-ons/breadcrumbs/

1. Create a file named `breadcrumbs.html` in the folder `layouts/partials` of your Hugo project

```html
<span>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    {{ range (split .URL "/") }}
        {{ if gt (len . ) 0 }}
            / <a href="/{{ . }}">{{ humanize (replace . "posts" "blog") }}</a>
        {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
</span>
```

2. Include `breadcrumbs.html` where you need it with:

`{{ partial "breadcrumbs.html" . }}`

Comment: This doesn't work for me with nested "sections", the links to the nested sections are broken (only the first link in the sequence is correct).

Comment: I have updated the code a little: http://hugocodex.org/add-ons/breadcrumbs/. It now looks for the actual page name, unless it shows an entry for a section, then it still humanizes the url part. The new (and old) code supports nested sections as long as you refrain from changing the permalink(s) in the config or the page.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote blog post on adding [breadcrumb partial for hugo with strucutred data](https://apoorv.blog/breadcrumb-json-ld-hugo/).

Don't just show machine readable breadcrumb to search engine crawler but also show the same to user also. My blog post goes into detail on the topic.

To answer this question here is my partial for only crawlers.

```html
{{ $url := replace .Permalink (printf "%s" .Site.BaseURL) ""}}
{{ .Scratch.Add "path" .Site.BaseURL }}
{{ .Scratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" .Site.BaseURL "name" "Home"))}}
{{ .Scratch.Add "permalink" .Permalink }}
{{ .Scratch.Add "title" .Title }}
{{ $pScratch := .Scratch }}

{{ range $index, $element := split $url "/" }}
  {{ $pScratch.Add "path" $element }}
  {{ $pScratch.Add "path" "/" }}
  {{ if ne $element "" }}
    {{ if eq ($pScratch.Get "path") ($pScratch.Get "permalink") }}
        {{ $pScratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" ($pScratch.Get "path") "name" ($pScratch.Get "title")))}}
    {{ else }}
        {{ $pScratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" ($pScratch.Get "path") "name" (humanize .)))}}
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}

<script type="application/ld+json">
  [{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [
      {{ range $index, $breadcrumb := .Scratch.Get "breadcrumb" }}
        {{ if ne $index 0 }},{{ end }}
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": {{ add $index 1 }},
            "name": "{{ $breadcrumb.name }}",
            {{ if ne $breadcrumb.url ($pScratch.Get "permalink") }}
              "item": {{ printf "%s" $breadcrumb.url }},
            {{ end }}
          }
      {{ end }}
      ]
    }
    {{ range $index, $category :=  .Params.categories }}
      ,
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Home",
            "item": "{{$.Site.BaseURL}}",
          },
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "name": "Categories",
            "item": "{{$.Site.BaseURL}}categories/",
          },
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 3,
            "name": "{{ humanize . }}",
            "item": "{{$.Site.BaseURL}}categories/{{.}}",
          },
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 4,
            "name": "{{ $pScratch.Get "title" }}",
          },
        ]
      }
    {{ end }}
    ]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can easily be solved by replacing.URL to .RelPermalink from [Lark Blumberg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105769/16496712) earlier from this timeline.

Step 1:

```
 <div class="container" id="breadcrumbs">
     <a href="/">Home</a>
     {{ range (split .RelPermalink "/") }}
         {{ if gt (len . ) 0 }}
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><a href="/{{ . }}">{{ humanize (replace . "posts" "blog") }}</a>
         {{ end }}
     {{ end }}
 </div>
```

Step 2:
Include breadcrumbs.html where you need it with:

```
{{ partial "breadcrumbs.html" . }}
```

For more information goto [Breadcrumbs | HugoCodex](https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/breadcrumbs/)